# taking control on vibration

Tags: iphone

I know this is what we use to make the device vibrate:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But how do I stop the vibration?
I mean, I want a switch which activates or deactivates the vibration.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` there's no way to know when the sound has stopped playing. For a vibration, I believe it's a fixed length action and I don't think you can stop it in the middle of its playing.

Comment: I am not talking about stoping vibration, while running.
i want provide an option to stop or to play vibration during the app/...

Comment: Then you need to add a setting and chose wether or not to play the vibration according to that setting.