# iOS Fine-grained control of vibration unit

Tags: ios, controls, iphone-vibrate

How much control do I have over the vibration unit on the iPhone?

I am simulating a plucked string, it would be fantastic if I could get the iPhone to vibrate in accord with the sound.

so,
a) is it possible to modulate the intensity of the vibration?
b) is it possible to change the duration?

Would it be possible to mimic a sharp attack that falls off gradually over a period of a few seconds?

I am aware that in older versions of iOS,  it was only possible to activate it.   both duration and intensity were fixed: [taking control on vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305824/taking-control-on-vibration)

is this still the case? Or has it become more flexible?

Comment: just a note, [iOS 6 may give the developer more control over the vibration unit](http://www.phonearena.com/news/iOS-6-minor-tweaks-that-you-might-like_id31135)

Comment: Were you able to find anything on this? I can't seem to find a way even with iOS 6 to have fine control over vibrate duration...

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 comes with an app that let's you design a [custom vibration](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/08/ios-5-allows-you-to-tap-out-custom-vibration-patterns/). The vibration is "designed" based on the user tapping on the phone.

That means it's technically feasible to create custom vibrations, but I don't know if there's an API for it. If there was in the newest SDK, it'd still be under NDA anyway.